# connection refused: how to configure apache james for localhost

Tags: linux, apache, email, telnet, james

I'm unclear on how to configure Apache James.  The [quick start guide](http://james.apache.org/server/3/quick-start.html) says:

```
Step 4: Configure
#################

  * All configuration files are embedded in jars.
  * We ship in the conf foler template configuration files.
  * You can override the default configuration : 
      Copy the conf folder any ...-template... you need and update according to your needs.
```

What does it mean that the configuration files are embedded in jars?  I should unzip all those jars to configure the files?

The directory structure:

```
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ 
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ tree -L 1
.
├── bin
├── conf
├── lib
├── LICENSE
├── log
├── NOTICE
├── README.crypto
├── README.txt
└── var

5 directories, 4 files
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ 
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ ll conf/
total 272
drwxr-xr-x 4 thufir thufir  4096 Aug 14 06:26 ./
drwxrwxr-x 7 thufir thufir  4096 Aug 14 06:26 ../
-rw------- 1 thufir thufir  2939 Mar 21 03:33 dnsservice-template.conf
-rw------- 1 thufir thufir  2903 Mar 21 03:33 domainlist-template.conf
-rw------- 1 thufir thufir 18715 Mar 21 03:33 fetchmail-template.conf
-rw------- 1 thufir thufir  1197 Mar 21 03:33 hbase-site-template.xml
-rw------- 1 thufir thufir  3466 Mar 21 03:33 imapserver-template.conf
-rw------- 1 thufir thufir  1645 Mar 21 03:33 james-database-template.properties
-rw------- 1 thufir thufir  3510 Mar 21 03:33 jcr-repository-template.xml
-rw------- 1 thufir thufir  1158 Mar 21 03:33 jmx-template.properties
drwxr-xr-x 2 thufir thufir  4096 Aug 14 06:26 lib/
-rw------- 1 thufir thufir  3325 Mar 21 03:33 lmtpserver-template.conf
-rw------- 1 thufir thufir  6944 Mar 21 03:33 log4j.properties
-rw------- 1 thufir thufir  7073 Mar 21 03:33 log4j-template.properties
-rw------- 1 thufir thufir  2885 Mar 21 03:33 mailbox-jcr-template.cnd
-rw------- 1 thufir thufir  1043 Mar 21 03:33 mailbox-maildir-template.properties
-rw------- 1 thufir thufir  1492 Mar 21 03:33 mailbox-template.conf
-rw------- 1 thufir thufir 30474 Mar 21 03:33 mailetcontainer-template.conf
-rw------- 1 thufir thufir  4172 Mar 21 03:33 mailrepositorystore-template.conf
drwxr-xr-x 3 thufir thufir  4096 Aug 14 06:26 META-INF/
-rw------- 1 thufir thufir  3528 Mar 21 03:33 pop3server-template.conf
-rw------- 1 thufir thufir  2497 Mar 21 03:33 recipientrewritetable-template.conf
-rw------- 1 thufir thufir 16011 Mar 21 03:33 smtpserver-template.conf
-rw------- 1 thufir thufir 43220 Mar 21 03:33 sqlResources-template.xml
-rw------- 1 thufir thufir 43220 Mar 21 03:33 sqlResources.xml
-rw------- 1 thufir thufir  1606 Mar 21 03:33 usersrepository23-template.conf
-rw------- 1 thufir thufir  3715 Mar 21 03:33 usersrepository-template.conf
-rw------- 1 thufir thufir 12596 Mar 21 03:33 wrapper.conf
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$
```

While I do see configuration files, which configuration file would enable me to telnet to James?

Attempts to connect:

```
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ 
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ bin/james console
Running Apache James Server App...
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    | 
jvm 1    | log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
jvm 1    | java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../log/james-server.log (Permission denied)
jvm 1    |  at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
jvm 1    |  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:207)
jvm 1    |  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:131)
jvm 1    |  at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
jvm 1    |  at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
jvm 1    |  at org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.activateOptions(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:223)
jvm 1    |  at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
jvm 1    |  at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
jvm 1    |  at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
jvm 1    |  at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:809)
jvm 1    |  at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:735)
jvm 1    |  at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCatsAndRenderers(PropertyConfigurator.java:639)
jvm 1    |  at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:504)
jvm 1    |  at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:547)
jvm 1    |  at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:483)
jvm 1    |  at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
jvm 1    |  at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:73)
jvm 1    |  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:242)
jvm 1    |  at org.apache.james.app.spring.JamesAppSpringMain.<clinit>(JamesAppSpringMain.java:34)
jvm 1    |  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
jvm 1    |  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
jvm 1    |  at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.<init>(WrapperSimpleApp.java:147)
jvm 1    |  at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.main(WrapperSimpleApp.java:485)
jvm 1    | log4j:ERROR Either File or DatePattern options are not set for appender [FILE].
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:33,381 | org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext | Refreshing org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext@1f5d386: startup date [Thu Aug 16 01:04:33 PDT 2012]; root of context hierarchy
jvm 1    | log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationUtils).
jvm 1    | log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
jvm 1    | log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:38,359 | org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext | Bean 'logprovider' of type [class org.apache.james.container.spring.lifecycle.LogProviderImpl] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:39,987 | james.mailrepositorystore | JamesMailStore init...
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:40,026 | james.mailrepositorystore | Registering Repository instance of class org.apache.james.mailrepository.file.FileMailRepository to handle file protocol requests for repositories with key file
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:40,026 | james.mailrepositorystore | Registering Repository instance of class org.apache.james.mailrepository.jdbc.JDBCMailRepository to handle db protocol requests for repositories with key db
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:40,027 | james.mailrepositorystore | Registering Repository instance of class org.apache.james.mailrepository.jdbc.JDBCMailRepository to handle dbfile protocol requests for repositories with key dbfile
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:40,027 | james.mailrepositorystore | Registering Repository instance of class org.apache.james.mailrepository.file.MBoxMailRepository to handle mbox protocol requests for repositories with key mbox
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:41,791 | james.dnsservice | Autodiscovery is enabled - trying to discover your system's DNS Servers
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:41,821 | james.dnsservice | Adding autodiscovered server 127.0.0.1
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:41,822 | james.dnsservice | Adding autodiscovered search path bounceme.net.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:41,833 | james.dnsservice | DNS Server is: 127.0.0.1
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:41,870 | james.dnsservice | Registered cache, resolver and search paths as DNSJava defaults
jvm 1    | 54  James  WARN   [WrapperSimpleAppMain] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'James', root URL [file:/home/thufir/apache-james-3.0-beta4/conf/]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:43,208 | james.domainlist | Set autodetect to: true
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:43,216 | james.domainlist | Set autodetectIP to: true
jvm 1    | 156  James  INFO   [WrapperSimpleAppMain] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 2.1.0
jvm 1    | 368  James  INFO   [WrapperSimpleAppMain] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DerbyDictionary".
jvm 1    | 7087  James  INFO   [WrapperSimpleAppMain] openjpa.Runtime - The Entity "org.apache.james.domainlist.jpa.model.JPADomain" was enhanced at level "2", but the current level of enhancement is "1,055,128". 
jvm 1    | 7094  James  INFO   [WrapperSimpleAppMain] openjpa.Runtime - A down level Entity was detected and logged. Please enable RUNTIME trace to see all down level Entities.
jvm 1    | WARN  01:04:51,660 | james.mailetcontext | The specified postmaster address ( postmaster@localhost ) is not a local address.  This is not necessarily a problem, but it does mean that emails addressed to the postmaster will be routed to another server.  For some configurations this may cause problems.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:52,153 | james.mailprocessor | Matcher All instantiated.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:52,214 | james.mailprocessor | Mailet PostmasterAlias instantiated.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:52,238 | james.mailprocessor | Matcher RelayLimit=30 instantiated.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:52,262 | james.mailprocessor | Mailet Null instantiated.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:52,284 | james.mailprocessor | Matcher SMTPAuthSuccessful instantiated.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:52,301 | james.mailprocessor | Mailet ToProcessor instantiated.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:52,302 | james.mailprocessor | Matcher All instantiated.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:52,314 | james.mailprocessor | Mailet ToProcessor instantiated.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:54,075 | james.mailprocessor | Matcher SMTPAuthSuccessful instantiated.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:54,085 | james.mailprocessor | Mailet SetMimeHeader instantiated.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:54,094 | james.mailprocessor | Matcher RecipientIsLocal instantiated.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:54,103 | james.mailprocessor | Mailet RecipientToLowerCase instantiated.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:54,104 | james.mailprocessor | Matcher RecipientIsLocal instantiated.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:54,547 | james.mailprocessor | Mailet LocalDelivery instantiated.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:54,556 | james.mailprocessor | Matcher HostIsLocal instantiated.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:54,558 | james.mailprocessor | Mailet ToProcessor instantiated.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:54,558 | james.mailprocessor | Matcher All instantiated.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:54,621 | james.mailetcontext | maxRetries is larger than total number of attempts specified.  Increasing last delayTime with 19 attempts 
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:54,621 | james.mailetcontext | Delay of 21600000 msecs is now attempted: 20 times
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:54,696 | james.mailprocessor | Mailet RemoteDelivery instantiated.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:56,336 | james.mailprocessor | Matcher All instantiated.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:56,387 | james.mailrepositorystore | Init org.apache.james.repository.file.FilePersistentObjectRepository Store
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:56,390 | james.mailrepositorystore | org.apache.james.repository.file.FilePersistentObjectRepository opened in ../var/mail/error
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:56,392 | james.mailrepositorystore | Init org.apache.james.repository.file.FilePersistentStreamRepository Store
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:56,393 | james.mailrepositorystore | org.apache.james.repository.file.FilePersistentStreamRepository opened in ../var/mail/error
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:56,395 | james.mailrepositorystore | added repository: file://var/mail/error/->org.apache.james.mailrepository.file.FileMailRepository
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:56,395 | james.mailprocessor | Mailet ToRepository instantiated.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:56,801 | james.mailprocessor | Matcher All instantiated.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:56,806 | james.mailrepositorystore | Init org.apache.james.repository.file.FilePersistentObjectRepository Store
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:56,807 | james.mailrepositorystore | org.apache.james.repository.file.FilePersistentObjectRepository opened in ../var/mail/spam
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:56,808 | james.mailrepositorystore | Init org.apache.james.repository.file.FilePersistentStreamRepository Store
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:56,808 | james.mailrepositorystore | org.apache.james.repository.file.FilePersistentStreamRepository opened in ../var/mail/spam
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:56,809 | james.mailrepositorystore | added repository: file://var/mail/spam/->org.apache.james.mailrepository.file.FileMailRepository
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:56,809 | james.mailprocessor | Mailet ToRepository instantiated.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:57,180 | james.mailprocessor | Matcher All instantiated.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:57,183 | james.mailrepositorystore | Init org.apache.james.repository.file.FilePersistentObjectRepository Store
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:57,183 | james.mailrepositorystore | org.apache.james.repository.file.FilePersistentObjectRepository opened in ../var/mail/address-error
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:57,184 | james.mailrepositorystore | Init org.apache.james.repository.file.FilePersistentStreamRepository Store
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:57,184 | james.mailrepositorystore | org.apache.james.repository.file.FilePersistentStreamRepository opened in ../var/mail/address-error
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:57,185 | james.mailrepositorystore | added repository: file://var/mail/address-error/->org.apache.james.mailrepository.file.FileMailRepository
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:57,185 | james.mailprocessor | Mailet ToRepository instantiated.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:57,633 | james.mailprocessor | Matcher All instantiated.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:57,636 | james.mailrepositorystore | Init org.apache.james.repository.file.FilePersistentObjectRepository Store
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:57,636 | james.mailrepositorystore | org.apache.james.repository.file.FilePersistentObjectRepository opened in ../var/mail/relay-denied
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:57,637 | james.mailrepositorystore | Init org.apache.james.repository.file.FilePersistentStreamRepository Store
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:57,637 | james.mailrepositorystore | org.apache.james.repository.file.FilePersistentStreamRepository opened in ../var/mail/relay-denied
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:57,637 | james.mailrepositorystore | added repository: file://var/mail/relay-denied/->org.apache.james.mailrepository.file.FileMailRepository
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:57,638 | james.mailprocessor | Mailet ToRepository instantiated.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:57,996 | james.mailprocessor | Matcher All instantiated.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:58,043 | james.mailprocessor | Mailet DSNBounce instantiated.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:58,398 | james.mailspooler | org.apache.james.mailetcontainer.impl.JamesMailSpooler init...
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:58,400 | james.mailspooler | org.apache.james.mailetcontainer.impl.JamesMailSpooler uses 20 Thread(s)
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:58,407 | james.mailspooler | Run org.apache.james.mailetcontainer.impl.JamesMailSpooler: dequeuer-1
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:58,407 | james.mailspooler | Queue=MailQueue:spool
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:58,423 | james.mailspooler | Run org.apache.james.mailetcontainer.impl.JamesMailSpooler: dequeuer-2
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:58,423 | james.mailspooler | Queue=MailQueue:spool
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:58,577 | james.fetchmail | FetchMail Disabled
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:58,807 | james.smtpserver | SMTP Service bound to: 0.0.0.0:25
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:58,808 | james.smtpserver | SMTP Service is running on: dur.bounceme.net
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:58,808 | james.smtpserver | SMTP Service handler hello name is: dur.bounceme.net
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:58,809 | james.smtpserver | SMTP Service handler connection timeout is: 360
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:58,809 | james.smtpserver | SMTP Service connection backlog is: 200
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:58,810 | james.smtpserver | This SMTP server requires authentication.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:04:58,810 | james.smtpserver | No maximum message size is enforced for this server.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:05:00,105 | james.mailspooler | org.apache.james.mailetcontainer.impl.JamesMailSpooler dispose...
jvm 1    | INFO  01:05:00,110 | james.mailspooler | Stop org.apache.james.mailetcontainer.impl.JamesMailSpooler: dequeuer-2
jvm 1    | INFO  01:05:00,113 | james.mailspooler | org.apache.james.mailetcontainer.impl.JamesMailSpooler thread shutdown completed.
jvm 1    | INFO  01:05:00,112 | james.mailspooler | Stop org.apache.james.mailetcontainer.impl.JamesMailSpooler: dequeuer-1
jvm 1    | 
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: Encountered an error running main: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'smtpserver': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /0.0.0.0:25
jvm 1    | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'smtpserver': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /0.0.0.0:25
jvm 1    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:135)
jvm 1    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
jvm 1    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1448)
jvm 1    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
jvm 1    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
jvm 1    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
jvm 1    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
jvm 1    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
jvm 1    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
jvm 1    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
jvm 1    |  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
jvm 1    |  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
jvm 1    |  at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
jvm 1    |  at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
jvm 1    |  at org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext.<init>(JamesServerApplicationContext.java:39)
jvm 1    |  at org.apache.james.app.spring.JamesAppSpringMain.init(JamesAppSpringMain.java:61)
jvm 1    |  at org.apache.james.app.spring.JamesAppSpringMain.main(JamesAppSpringMain.java:42)
jvm 1    |  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
jvm 1    |  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
jvm 1    |  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
jvm 1    |  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
jvm 1    |  at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
jvm 1    |  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
jvm 1    | Caused by: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /0.0.0.0:25
jvm 1    |  at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:298)
jvm 1    |  at org.apache.james.protocols.netty.AbstractAsyncServer.bind(AbstractAsyncServer.java:101)
jvm 1    |  at org.apache.james.protocols.lib.netty.AbstractConfigurableAsyncServer.init(AbstractConfigurableAsyncServer.java:274)
jvm 1    |  at org.apache.james.protocols.lib.netty.AbstractServerFactory.init(AbstractServerFactory.java:75)
jvm 1    |  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
jvm 1    |  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
jvm 1    |  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
jvm 1    |  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
jvm 1    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:346)
jvm 1    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:299)
jvm 1    |  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:132)
jvm 1    |  ... 22 more
jvm 1    | Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
jvm 1    |  at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
jvm 1    |  at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:137)
jvm 1    |  at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:77)
jvm 1    |  at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.bind(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:140)
jvm 1    |  at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleServerSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:92)
jvm 1    |  at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:66)
jvm 1    |  at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.bind(Channels.java:462)
jvm 1    |  at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:186)
jvm 1    |  at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap$Binder.channelOpen(ServerBootstrap.java:343)
jvm 1    |  at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelOpen(Channels.java:170)
jvm 1    |  at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.<init>(NioServerSocketChannel.java:77)
jvm 1    |  at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannelFactory.newChannel(NioServerSocketChannelFactory.java:137)
jvm 1    |  at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannelFactory.newChannel(NioServerSocketChannelFactory.java:85)
jvm 1    |  at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:277)
jvm 1    |  ... 32 more
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$
```

The configuration file (doesn't fit):

https://gist.github.com/3368324

Comment: Can you show us java --version ?

Comment: @NlightNfotis switched to openjdk6 and updated the question.  At least now there are error messages.  Dunno why nothing showed in the logs earlier.

Comment: From your logs, I can see that James has issues with accessing the log file too. Maybe trying to run it as root will give it enough privileges to at least locate the log file.

Comment: Also, have you tried controlling james via its cli: james-cli -h localhost -p 25

Comment: it was strictly a matter of running `bin/james console` with sudo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Most UNIX systems require superuser privileges to open sockets below
>   1024, which includes the IANA-standard SMTP (on port 25), POP3 (on
>   port 110) and IMAP4 (on port 143). These default ports can be changed
>   in the conf file (read for pop3, smtp and imap4. Obviously, you would
>   then need to reconfigure your clients. This may not be an option if
>   you want to receive mail from external mail servers.

This text is from the james installation guide found [here](http://james.apache.org/server/3/install.html). Have you tried to run james as the root user to try to bind to the port 25? Try this: `sudo ./james start`. If this doesn't seem to work, you might be able to change the ports for the respective services in their respective configuration file: **smtpserver.conf for smtp**, might interest you, seeing you are trying to use smtp server.

**[EDIT]:** You can open the configuration files in any standard text editor, **like nano, vi, emacs, gedit, etc...**

**[EDIT #2]:** Do you have the proper java implementation required to run james? From the installation guide:

> James requires a Java Runtime Environment. Java version 1.5 or higher
>   is required to run the James application. The exact JREs available
>   depend on the platform. In addition, the environment variable
>   JAVA_HOME should be set to the JRE home directory before running
>   James.
>
> If you run JDK7, James will not start due to a bug in JAXB. As
>   temporary workaround, you can download the latest 2.1 version of JAXB
>   from http://jaxb.java.net/2.1.13/JAXB2_20100510.jar and copy the
>   extracted jaxb-impl.jar into conf/lib.
>
> James 3.0 has been successfully tested on OpenJDK, Sun JDK and IBM JDK

If I were you, I would opt to download OpenJDK version 1.6 and see where it goes. As a sidenote, have you tried to use `./james help`, and see if there is anything helpful there? Furthermore, try to attach any log files james may be producing in your question to help us inspect the problem further.

Comment: hmm, same result with sudo, exactly the same.  good idea though, I think it's an OS something.  I'm not using SMTP at this stage, just thufir@localhost to foo@localhost.  I'll poke around a bit though.

Comment: that was a good catch about jaxb, I added the corresponding jar.  Editing the **template** for dnsservice-template.conf has a section on IP address, I removed the comment so that it's 127.0.0.1 now.

Comment: `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'smtpserver': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /0.0.0.0:25`  looks like a bad ip address there, not localhost.

Comment: YES! 0.0.0.0 is reserved as a special ip afaik! Localhost is bound to 127.0.0.1 which is also presented as ::1 sometimes. Try to see if you can configure the ip somewhere.

Comment: maybe a sandbox problem?  `jvm 1    | Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied`

Comment: I think there is a configuration file called jmx.properties or something. Check to see if it has anything of worth there!

Comment: it's smtp as you've said all along:  `jvm 1    | INFO  00:44:57,724 | james.smtpserver | SMTP Service bound to: 0.0.0.0:25`   I'll look in config files again.

Comment: it's very weird.  I see 127.0.0.0 and 0.0.0.0 ip addresses everywhere in smtp config file.  changing to 127.0.0.1 but same problem.

Comment: Are you sure the changes to these files are saved? If they are, then maybe it sounds like a bug or something, or maybe another configuration file must overlap with these ones. If they are not try to make changes as root, then run it again.

Comment: I think that smtpserver-template.conf is supposed to copied somewhere, I don't understand that instruction.  Pardon, how do I run the CLI version?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15409/discussion-between-thufir-and-nlightnfotis)

Comment: Ok, I re-downloaded James.  All you need to do is to use sudo to get it to run.  If that's in the documentation, I didn't see it.  The whole IP address thing is a red-herring in just getting James to start.

Comment: Well, I am using the latest version of James (3.3.0), I have gone and changed ALL the ports to be above 1024, but still... I get the same error as here. It still logs the `0.0.0.0:25`. How could one explain this...? Where the hack is this setting coming from? I have searched the entire James installation and there is nothing! I hate running things as root. I am a Windows user and I don't do that on Windows either! Maybe the james mailing list provides some answers...